# Porque al actualizar una ves el treeview no me deja volver a actualizar en tkinter

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

Porque al actualizarlo una vez, si apreto en otra opcion y le doy actualizar no cambia el valor del treeview por ejemplo esta vacio, selecciono administrador apreto actualizar y carga, pero si lo cambio a empleado y apreto actualizar no se actualiza porque ?

Dejo una imagen de ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dejo el pedazo de codigo donde tengo la tabla y donde tengo la funcion de actualizar

```
        self.tabla = ttk.Treeview(frame1, height=4, columns=('#1', '#2', '#3'),selectmode="browse")
        self.tabla.grid(row=0,column=0)
        

        self.tabla.heading("#0", text="ID", anchor=CENTER )
        self.tabla.heading("#1", text="NOMBRE", anchor=CENTER)
        self.tabla.heading("#2", text="APELLIDO", anchor=CENTER)
        self.tabla.heading("#3", text="RANGO", anchor=CENTER)

        self.tabla.column("#0", width = 50 , stretch=NO, anchor=CENTER)
        self.tabla.column("#1", width = 130 , stretch=NO, anchor=CENTER)
        self.tabla.column("#2", width = 130 , stretch=NO, anchor=CENTER)
        self.tabla.column("#3", width = 130 , stretch=NO, anchor=CENTER)
        
        Rango = self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())["text"]
        Label(vent_privilegios, text="Actualizar Permiso", bg="#83D6A8",font=("arial 18 bold")).place(x=140,y=150)
        
        self.checkbox_value = StringVar(vent_privilegios)

        Radiobutton(vent_privilegios,text="EMPLEADO / ", value="Empleado", bg="#83D6A8", font = ("arial 10 bold") ,variable=self.checkbox_value).place(x=120, y=183)
        Radiobutton(vent_privilegios,text="ADMINISTRADOR", value="Administrador", bg="#83D6A8" , font=("arial 10 bold") ,variable=self.checkbox_value).place(x=230, y=183)

        boton_act = Button(vent_privilegios, text="Actualizar", width=30,font=("arial 12 bold"), command=lambda: self.editando(self.checkbox_value.get(), Rango))
        boton_act.config(bd=2,relief="solid")
        boton_act.place(x=100, y=220)
```

y aca dejo la funcion que actua al apretar el boton

````
     def editando(self, checkbox_value, Rango):
        if self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())["text"] == "":
            self.mensaje["text"] = "Por favor, seleccione un elemento"
            return     
        consulta = "UPDATE Personal SET Rango = ?  WHERE Rango = ? "
        parametros = (checkbox_value, Rango)
        self.ejecuta_consulta(consulta, parametros)
        self.obtener_personal()  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tu objeto `Rango` lo creas una sola vez y luego no lo cambias, esa primera vez que lo creas le das un valor (por ejemplo, "administrador"), y luego si modificas el `RadioButton` seleccionado, `Rango` sigue siendo "administrador". Adicionalmente, como estás trabajando con un objeto, no es necesario que le pases atributos del objeto a la función (ya que la función puede obtenerlos de todas formas).

Puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```
def editando(self):
    rango = self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())["text"]
    checkbox_value = self.checkbox_value.get()
    if self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())["text"] == "":
        self.mensaje["text"] = "Por favor, seleccione un elemento"
        return     
    consulta = "UPDATE Personal SET Rango = ?  WHERE Rango = ? "
    parametros = (checkbox_value, rango)
    self.ejecuta_consulta(consulta, parametros)
    self.obtener_personal()
```

Como adicional, [la documentación de Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) recomienda que no uses palabras con la primera letra en mayúsculas como nombre de variable (por ejemplo: `Variable = 123`), sino que uses minúsculas separadas con guiones (p. ej: `mi_variable = 123`), porque las mayúsculas suelen ser usadas como nombres de clases (y, por ende, crear objetos).